# Camera Preview Session setRepeatingRequest focus issue, focuses only first time ontouch

Tags: android, android-activity, camera, touch, ontouch

i have a textureview where i have implemented ontouch listener, i want when i touch the display to be able to focus, but there's a problem when setting setRepeatingRequest to build the display, it focuses only first time when i touch and after that i can touch 100x but still it has no effect, i want to enable flash on focusing and on capture but the flash stays on all the time as the camera does not focus, please help me, i'm stuck for 5 days at this task !

Here is my code : 
     //meteringRectangleArr is the areas where i can focus (metering)

```
    mPreviewCaptureRequestBuilder.set(
                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER,
                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_CANCEL);

                mPreviewCaptureRequestBuilder.set(
                        CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_REGIONS,
                        meteringRectangleArr);

                mPreviewCaptureRequestBuilder.set(
                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_REGIONS,
                        meteringRectangleArr);

                mPreviewCaptureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE,
                        CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);

                mPreviewCaptureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                        CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_AUTO);

                mPreviewCaptureRequestBuilder.set(
                        CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER,
                        CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_START);

                if(flash_value == 1){
                    flash_startime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    updateFlashingView();
                    mPreviewCaptureRequestBuilder.set(
                            CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE,
                            CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_SINGLE);
                }

                else if (flash_value == 0){
                    mPreviewCaptureRequestBuilder.set(
                            CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE,
                            CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                }

                try {

                    mCameraCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(
                        mPreviewCaptureRequestBuilder.build(),
                        null, mBackgroundHandler);

                } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

remove this:

```
mPreviewCaptureRequestBuilder.set(
                        CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER,
                        CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_START);
```

you should call CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_START only once, using mCameraCaptureSession.capture.

I branched form [google's Camera2Basic example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) and changed it to use `CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_AUTO` instead of `CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE`

You can take the project from git and see how it works - https://github.com/pinhassi/android-Camera2Basic